# Selecting event target element in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, events

I have a form with various navigation buttons at the bottom. If the user makes changes to the form and then clicks any link or button besides these, they should be given a browser alert warning them about unsaved changes.

The navigation buttons all have the data attribute `data-save-form`, and the script is currently as follows:

```
var formChanged = false;

$('form').on('change', 'input, textarea, select', function () {
    formChanged = true;
});

$(window).on('beforeunload', function (e) {
    if (!$(e.target.activeElement).is('[data-save-form]') && formChanged) {
        return "Changes you made may not be saved. You can save your progress by clicking the 'Save and Exit' button at the bottom of the page.";
    }
});
```

However, IE's event object doesn't seem to have a `target.activeElement` property. How can I find this element, or is there a better way to approach this?

This is an older site using jQuery 1.11.0, but I'm sure it's not essential to use it for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working by capturing the `mousedown` event target and using that if `e.target.activeElement` was undefined.

```
var targetElement;

$(window).on('mousedown', function (e) {
    targetElement = e.target;
});

$(window).on('beforeunload', function (e) {
    var target = e.target.activeElement || targetElement;
    if (!$(target).is('[data-save-form]') && formChanged) {
        return "Changes you made may not be saved. You can save your progress by clicking the 'Save and Exit' button at the bottom of the page.";
    }
});
```

I saw a solution like this on another SO post previously but couldn't get it working. If I find it I'll link it.